# Semicolon and Single Quote Issue in SQL Insert Statements

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am executing a SQL script which has spaces, semicolons, single-quotes, special characters etc. in of the column called prod_desc.
I need to execute the script from SQLPLUS. I have the set the following in the SQLPLUS however, single quotes, semicolons are not taken into consideration.

```
set sqlblanklines on
```

See the below insert statement for instance, semicolon is after the line break. This is causing an error during execution. How can I resolve the issue?

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into PROD_DESC
   (PROD_NO, PROD_DESC
    )
Values
   ('XYZ', 'test
semicolon test;
'
);
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE prod_desc
(
   prod_no     VARCHAR2 (100),
   prod_desc   VARCHAR2 (1000)
);
```

Comment: You have to escape Special character

Comment: @Jens How do I do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm#20741

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espace the semicolon:

```
SET DEF OFF;
Insert into PROD_DESC(PROD_NO, PROD_DESC)
Values('XYZ', 'test semicolon test\;');
```

Comment: Is there a way to SET in sqlplus like SET DEFINE OFF:?

Comment: The reason is I have a huge SQL file which has many cases with case I have shown in the question.

Comment: To set the escape character or to escape all characters with just a directive?

Comment: Both examples would be highly helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can use the "  set escape '\' " to set the escape character; However, I'm not sure you can escape all characters with just a directive (at least I don't know a way).

Answer (score 4):

I also like to use the q-quote syntax. It removes the need for escaping, and makes quoting quotes much easier.

The syntax is

```
q'[ <your string> ]'
```

`<Your string>` can contain quotes or any other characters the normally need escaping. The [ can actually be substituted for or "paired" characters, such as {} or ().

For example:

```
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE prod_desc
  2  (
  3     prod_no     VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     prod_desc   VARCHAR2 (100)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF;
SQL> Insert into PROD_DESC
  2     (PROD_NO, PROD_DESC
  3      )
  4  Values
  5     ('XYZ', q'[test
  6  semicolon test
  7  ; ]'
  8  );

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> select * from prod_desc;

PROD_NO    PROD_DESC
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XYZ        test
           semicolon test
           ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore semicolons in a string with

```
SET SQLTERMINATOR OFF
```